# Pusher error: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 6001: Connection refused

Tags: laravel, vue.js, websocket, pusher

I'm developing an application with separate Laravel 10 and Vue 3. I wanted to implement real time events with Laravel broadcasting but I'm running into some problems.

I connect to the websockets from the frontend, but I get nothing and when I try to trigger the event from the backend I get the Curl error.

## BACKEND LARAVEL

websockets.php

```
`'apps' => [
        [
            'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'path' => env('PUSHER_APP_PATH'),
            'capacity' => null,
            'enable_client_messages' => false,
            'enable_statistics' => true,
        ],
    ],`
```

broadcasting.php

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => false,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'http',
                'useTLS' => false
            ],
        ],
```

.env (laravel)

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
PUSHER_APP_ID=local
PUSHER_APP_KEY=local
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=local
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=eu
PUSHER_SCHEME=http
```

in api.php

```
/**
 * Live EVENTS
 */
Route::get('/test', function () {
    event(new UpdateUser());
});
```

Events/UpdateUser.php

```
class UpdateUser implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function broadcastWith(): array
    {
        return ['message' => 'Hello, Vue!'];
    }

    public function broadcastOn(): Channel
    {
        return new Channel('userupdate-channel');
    }
}
```

app.php

```
'providers' => ServiceProvider::defaultProviders()->merge([
        /*
         * Package Service Providers...
         */

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
    ])->toArray(),
```

## FRONTEND VUE

.env

```
VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY=local
VITE_PUSHER_APP_HOST='127.0.0.1'
VITE_PUSHER_CLUSTER='eu'
```

main.js

```
//Laravel Notifications
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'
import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
window.Pusher = Pusher

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: 'eu',
    wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_HOST,
    wsPort: 6001,
    forceTLS: false,
    encrypted: false,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws'],
    //enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
})
```

The versions i used:
"pusher-js": "^4.3.1",
"laravel-echo": "^1.15.3",

On frontend:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipa2q.png)

I developing in local with lando.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Pusher is an application/service hosted outside of your local machine. Here is the [pusher link](https://pusher.com/).

Pusher cannot be accessed from **127.0.01** and port **6001**. When you create an account with Pusher and create an application from their website, you'll get the credentials. And you'll have to use those credentials. When using pusher, you can simply omit **host** **port**s and the package will take care of those configs.

But, if you don't want to buy the subscription from Pusher, you can use self-hosted pusher implementation using [Laravel-Websockets](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/introduction)

Or at least in your local environment, to test your application you can use the laravel-websockets. In this case, as the service will be in your local machine, the host with **127.0.0.1:6001** will be available and you can test out the application.

Comment: Hi @ssi-anik and thanks for your answer.

I'm already using laravel-websockets, sorry if I didn't put it in the question, in fact when I go to the /laravel-websockets endpoint and click "connect", everything works. The server is listening on 127.0.0.1 and port 6001.

However, when I visit the test endpoint to fire the event, I get the curl error and Vue receives nothing.

Comment: Are you using docker?

Comment: Yes Docker version 23.0.4, build f480fb1 with Lando (3.11)

Comment: Update your answer with the `docker-compose ps` or something equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I found out that works with Laravel 11 and 10 Breeze with pusher is to change your settings to https. Download Curl (cacert.pem) : https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html, and then change your php.ini settings:

`curl.cainfo =C:\Users\to\path\cacert.pem openssl.cafile=C:\Users\DaveMann\openssl\cacert.pem`

console.log visible in browser:  f12->levels-> verbose